# Question about electronics kits as gifts for an 8 years old

Tags: discussion

I don't know where to ask this question. It has to do with electronics and electrical engineering, but only as a tool for learning.

What I need are suggestions for a beginning electronics kit for an 8 year old. I know everyone says that their 8 year old is the smartest kid ever, but this isn't my child so I'm good (nephew). He's a smart kid, very intuitive and curious, and I'd like to give him the opportunity to get into electronics. If anyone has any suggestions for kits that I should look at, I'd be very grateful. I'm kind of at a loss as to where I should start him. I think anything with programming is probably out of his pay grade at this point.

If this question would be better elsewhere please let me know gently and I'll post it there, and I apologize.

Comment: It's not on-topic anywhere on these sites.

Comment: That was unnecessary, this topic was answered almost 2 weeks ago. Also I posted it on Meta, so...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for asking.

This would be a topic for chat. Even if you avoid asking for specific product recommendations (which would be off-topic), the discussion would be largely anecdotal and opinion-based, which would also be off-topic.